# Android WebView executing javascript too fast

Tags: android, kotlin

On my app, I have a series of Javascript strings that my class funnels into a queue for a WebView to evaluate. The issue is that when I test my scripts with buttons they work fine, but the JavaScript evaluates too quickly when I combine them and it doesn't return any values.

So far I have tried `onPageFinished`,`Thread.sleep()`, a semaphore, and `postVisualStateCallback()` to no avail. How can I get the runScripts() function to wait until the previous line has made any change it wants to make before executing?

````
protected fun runScripts() {
        for (line in scriptsQueue) {
            line?.let {
                when (line) {
                    ("wait") -> {
                        Thread.sleep(1000)
                    else -> {
                        driver.evaluateJavascript(line) { Log.d("webDebug", it) }
                        Thread.sleep(3_000)}
                }
            }
            scriptsQueue.clear()
            Log.d("scrape", "All scripts executed. Contents: $scriptsQueue")
        } ```
````

Answer (score 0):

The evaluateJavascript function is asynchronous  It takes as a parameter a callback that is called when it's done.  Anything you wish to do after the javascript is run should be put in that callback. Since you have N callbacks here, you need to wait for all N callbacks to be finished.  The easiest way of doing that is to use a Semaphore initialized to having -N permits.  Then wait on the Semaphore after the loop.  In each callback, give 1 permit back to the semaphore.  This way the semaphore will release for the outer loop when all N callbacks are finished.

Comment: I'll try that now, thanks!